# Chunk output without knitrout and verbatim environment

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

```
<<newChunk,echo=FALSE,comment=NA,background=NA>>=
x <- "\\includegraphics[width=\\maxwidth]{figure/Kompetenz1.pdf}"
cat(x)
@
```

If I run this r code in my .Rnw file I will get the following output in my .tex file:

```
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1, 1, 1}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
\begin{verbatim}
\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{figure/Kompetenz1.pdf}
\end{verbatim}
\end{kframe}
\end{knitrout}
```

How can I get just the \includegraphics{...} without any environment in my .tex file?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are using Knitr in the first place.  It looks like your just trying to include a PDF in your latex document.  To do that I would use the command:

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{figure/Kompetenz1.pdf}
```

or

```
\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{figure/Kompetenz1.pdf}
```

In your Rnw file.  No need for a Knitr chunk here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @baptiste was right.

Why I was using a Knitr chunk was to loop over some values. Here is my example code:

```
<<Ueberblick, echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'>>=
for(i in 1:nrow(Kompetenzen)){ 
    cat(paste("\\includegraphics[width=\\maxwidth]figure/Kompetenz.pdf}",i," \\newline ",sep=""))
}

@
```

Thanks for the help!